# Django table rendering blank rows

Tags: python, django

I've searched far and wide, and haven't come up with a solution despite this probably being a simple fix.

Models.py:

```py
class Leaderboard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Score(models.Model):
    leaderboard = models.ForeignKey(Leaderboard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    time_set = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.player_name} - {self.leaderboard} [{self.score}]"
```

views.py

```py
def index(response, name):
    # ls = Leaderboard.objects.get(name=name)
    sorted = Leaderboard.objects.filter(name=name).order_by('-score')
    return render(response, "highscores/leaderboard_ranks.html", {"ls": sorted})
```

And the relevant template part of the code.

```html
{% for item in ls %}
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>{{item.player_name}}</td>
<td>{{item.score}}</td>
<td>{{item.time_set}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And this just outputs blank rows in the table. What am I missing?

Comment: You have a list of Leaderboard objects and you're trying to access them via Score model attributes.

Comment: Ah good catch, that worked! Thanks!